# is using attributes for microdata storage and as a selector a bad thing

Tags: jquery

So I have a habit of using the attribute lang as my selector and store microdata,in jquery.

Althought it is not w3 compliant.But is it a good thing.
Also is there any alternative to this.

something like this. $('[lang=153]') to get this dom and $(this)[0].lang to get the data.

Comment: Maybe show an example of what you are doing?

Comment: `.data` can be a good alternative. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: something like this.
$('[lang=153]') to get this dom 
and $(this)[0].lang to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the data into your element using the data- prefix:

```
<div data-lang="123">Text</div>
```

Then you can select this element and read the data like this:

```
var lang = $('[data-lang="123"]').data('lang');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C3LCp/

Answer (score 1):

As you said, it's not w3 compliant. That's not the worst thing your site can face, but it's definetly not a good one.
The advantage of your method is that you can make more use of selectors this way.
I recommend, since you use jquery, using the `data` method to store data(any type of object -  much more than a simple `lang=`) right on the selected dom element.

Answer (score 1):

To store data with jquery you should use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

You store data:

```
 $('#myid').data('mydata', 'mydata')
```

and you retrieve it:

```
 $('#myid').data('mydata')
```

You can also write your element with an attribute and access it:

```
<div id='myid' data-mydata='this is the data'></div>

var my = $('#myid').data('mydata'); //my is equal to 'this is the data'
```

Comment: but I want to use as a dom

eg:
I find some id on some click 
id=13
and want to do something with a dom related to this id
$('[lang='+13+']')

Comment: I updated my answer i don't understand fully what do you mean

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't cause a problem, although it causes your HTML to be 'non compliant'.

HTML5 is introducing a valid way of doing this using attributes that start with `data-` like this:

```
<div data-billy="bob"></div>
```

I would suggest switching to that style. See [John Resig's](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) explanation for more info.

Comment: can data  attributes be used as selectors and can this work with 
ie

Comment: They're conceptually no different from what you're using now and can be used as selectors in jQuery.